# How to manage ios background modes via react native (for example calling API while app is killed)

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm developing a react-native app and I'm facing a problem: I need to execute a periodical task (an API call to post some data) in all possible cases: the app is in the background, app is in foreground and app is killed (double tap on the home button and swipe up).

How could I achieve this in iOS?

For Android, HeadlessJS seems to work fine, but for iOS I couldn't find anything which could fit my case.

I've tried with react-native-background-fetch but if the app is killed, also the background fetch is halted (https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch/issues/34)

I've tried react-native-background-timer, but it works only until the app is killed.

I've also tried adding a geolocation native library to set background mode "location updates" capability, and calling its start method inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions into AppDelegate.m. But also this works only until the app is killed.
If I use the same native library on a native iOS app, and I call it inside the same method into AppDelegate.m, it keeps working also when the app is killed.

So which is the difference between the native and react-native app that lets the app survive the force-quit?

I've also tried reading this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html but I couldn't replicate that info via react-native.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Any solution on that?

Comment: Hi any success on this ? I have the same problem